# Is it possible to import typescript into html ans a color value or edit a color value from html in typescript

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have been working on this piece of code for like two days now. I am using Angular to create a web app, and I need some numbers to change color when they reach a certain value. (EXAMPLE: if num > 45 color = green else color = red) I would like to be able to pass the value of color between my typescript and HTML, but I'm having trouble with that. The color value passes to HTML just fine, but I can't put the color value into any type of style.
Here is my code. Thanks for the help!

**Typescript:**

```
colorOption=''

if(this.Classyaverage > 45){
  console.log('red')
  this.colorOption='#FF0000'
}
else{
  console.log('green')
  this.colorOption='#00FF00'
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="pagecolor">

    <div class="box">

      <canvas class="offset"
      id="lineChart" 
      width="240"
      height="180" 
      >
      </canvas>

      //This is what I want...

      <style>
       h1{ color:{{colorOption}};}
      </style>

      <h1>
        {{Classyaverage}}
      </h1>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

So is I can't import a Typescript like that, is it possible to export HTML or CSS into typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use ngStyle on h1 tag (https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

```
  <h1 [ngStyle]="{'color': colorOption}">
    {{Classyaverage}}
  </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a css class where you will apply the color:

```css
.myColor {
    color: var(--colorVariable);
}
```

Assign the value of the css variable from the typescript according to what you need in this way:

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty( '--colorVariable', '#00FF00' );
```

You can modify it from any calculation or event of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is  the ngClass directive.
Here is the documentation from Angular. https://campuslabs.visualstudio.com/Student%20Assessment/_workitems/edit/59235

```
// .css

.red{
  color: #f00;
} 

.green: {
 color: #0f0
}
```

-

```
// .html

<h1 [ngClass]="{'red': Classyaverage > 45, 'green': Classyaverage <= 45}"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be more than you need, but if you wanted to style multiple elements (such as all of a class or tag name) you could do the following.

HTML:

```
<h1 class="color-change">
  {{Classyaverage}}
</h1>
<h2 class="color-change" *ngFor"let el of arr">
  test
</h2>
```

TypeScript:

```
@ViewChildren(".color-change") private colorChange: QueryList<ElementRef>;
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.colorChange.subscribe(() => 
    this.colorChange.forEach((element: ElementRef) => {
      this.renderer.setStyle(
        element.nativeElement,
        'color',
        this.colorOption
      })
    })
  );
}
...
```

This would take care of multiple elements as well as asynchronous elements

Comment: Of course @naga-sai-a 's answer is shorter and would be better if it were just a single static element since this has much larger overhead.